# customizing upload.aspx form

Tags: 2007, document-library, file-upload

I wanted to add a text box to a document library upload form so when I try to upload document I can fill that text box.

I also wanted it in "upload.aspx" to add it to when the document library is created.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to customise the upload form but why not create a text column that is a mandatory field. They way, when you upload a document the user will be forced to fill it in.

Something like [this](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_o7Td6KCGNTA/TI9j0icVMPI/AAAAAAAAAjY/7xcHmb8gIUc/image_thumb%5B3%5D.png)